# Delays between Iterations of a for-loop in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, for-loop, delay

I'am strugeling with making delays in GWT (client-side).

What I want is to have a break of a few seconds between the iterations of a for-loop.
The first iteration should start instantly, but there has to be a pause between the following ones.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: why do you achieve through it?  do you need something show in between looping? you are facing problem because java script is single thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can delay by using [`Timer`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html).

Try something like this:

```java
Timer timer = new Timer() { 
    public void run { 
        // Whatever code you want to repeat
    } 
};

for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    timer.schedule(100) //100 millisecond delay
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Threading concept could be used for your question

you could try having a counter of loop and check for condition inside loop that if counter is >1 the use thread sleep for some seconds...